# Find ascii of every character in a string split by '-'

Tags: c, string, ascii

So, i want to make a program in c where you input a string then the output will be ascii number of every character in that string split by '-'. i almost done then i dont know how to remove the last '-' in the output of my code. exp. input: abc output: 97-98-99.
Here is my code :

```
    char s[1001];
    
    scanf("%s",&s);
    for(int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++){
        printf("%d-",s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My output : 97-98-99-

Comment: you can use `strlen` function to obtain the length of your input and than do not print the dash when you are at the last char

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not change the scope of your question after you got answers. Generally, each post shall only contain one question. If you want to ask different things, please ask a new question. I will rollback your edit.

Comment: @piertoni a `strlen()` call is not needed here.

Comment: @chux-reinstate-monica when a guy is learning you don't have and don't need to suggest the more efficient solution (that probably is obscure), but the most easy to understand. Everyone can catch a concepts with a different example... so I prefer to add a bit o variety than stick to common solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly rearrange your logic:

```
for(int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++){
  if( i != 0 )
    printf("-");
  printf("%d",s[i]);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, may i ask again what if i want to add some number test case for the input what the code will be ? for ex. 
input :
2
abc
hello

output :
Case#1. 97-98-99
Case#2. 104-101-108-108-111

Answer (score 4):

We'll use [Ternary Operator](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/c-ternary-operator/), to check whether `i` is the last character before `'\0'` by checking `s[i + 1] != 0`, here `i` is the current index of the string. Here's a [visual representation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/images/string_representation.jpg).

*NOTE: Your variable `char s[1001]` will be decayed to a pointer (exception: `sizeof` operator).*

#### Some improvements:

- Don't use `"%s"`, use `"%<WIDTH>s"`, to avoid [buffer-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71232480/17939455)
- Use `size_t` to iterate through an array.
- Instead of using bare `return 0;`, use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, which is defined in the header file `stdlib.h`.
- always check whether `scanf()` input was successful or not

#### Final Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[1001] = {0};
    if (scanf("%1000s", s) != 1)
    {
        perror("bad input");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i]; i++)
        printf("%d%s", s[i], (s[i + 1]) ? "-" : "");
    puts("\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### Output:

```
Hello
72-101-108-108-111
```

Comment: You can use a define for the array size, and '%*s' with sizeof in scanf in order to avoid "magic number" 1000 and 1001. You don't need the variable "len" either, so you can simplify this code further. I know, i'm nitpicking ...

Comment: Because you can do `for (size_t i = 0; s[i]; i++)` for the loop (since '\0' is equal to 0) and you can do `(s[i + 1]) ? "-" : ""` for the ternary.

Answer (score 0):

check if current index is not the **last index** then print `-` otherwise it's the last index and print `newline`

```
char s[1001];

scanf("%s",&s);

int len = 0;

for(;s[len]!='\0';len++);

for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    printf("%d",s[i]);
    if(i+1 != len)
       printf("-")
    else
        printf("\n")
}
```

Comment: I think my solution is way easier and less complex

Comment: Solutions are just a personal approach and making such comments is not in the spirit of SO. I suggest that you restrain yourself from making such in the future.

Comment: @Gnqz I think the less complex and hence easier approach is a fact. There was no disrespect intended.

Comment: SO uses a voting system and this is how the higher quality content gets distinguished from the rest. I'm by no means a SO representative neither I intend to disrespect your own opinion, but if you are willing to take a piece of advice from me - let your answers/content speak for itself, there is no need to compare it to the others.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `strlen()`, *length* or repeated tests in a loop, simply change the separator.

```
const char *separator = "";
for (size_t i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++) {
    printf("%s%d",separator, s[i]);
    separator = "-";
}
```