# Digital Root in c

Tags: c, scanf, buffer

So you have to do:

```
11 = 1+1 = 2

3578 = 3+5+7+8 = 23 = 2+3 = 5
```

But the problem is that the number can be very large(consist of 10,000 digits)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    char buffer[100000];
    scanf("%99999s", buffer);
    unsigned long long int result = 0;
    for( unsigned idx = 0; isdigit(buffer[idx]); idx++ ){
        result = (int)buffer[idx] + result - '0';
    }
    int result2 = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    while ( result > 0 ){
        digit = result % 10;
        result2 += digit;
        result = result / 10;
        if( result <= 0 && result2 > 9){
            result = result2;
            result2 = 0;
            continue;
        }
    }
    printf("RESULT : %d\n",result2);
}
```

**Input** :

```
751681014401040450622780075254045270442210812770460775451184384531483702082226416361544531414410171607350014850333878358743220376871078174403200044662362218387877088216176613360252864405743551700372186186575780774423365770110772762276064451888336156654128153746808000717416854455788814078402738512314518407278677742343615032578760156411281210127537668157717015666162165516525027107402068668123177553108546580071328732081607873181528418805507115473871188671175418353685287375851146862706642660460660640361450625482328733578704685372147576117063756404450651264407575360484374363385487210664552841370274325526483461688624004361174850045865227812614165458631837856673343826214104801877607136035412561647757156215008153430481053606347145474412241557035145221136028312706780031881775353428185131338124663027888077214386322084144228202118607125173881566084750330384756507240153360252125102231317116187460551751644005660558858277077053174524651718580360376435305240031868065863876643181746460523888528353776530743505576145346723312843737184587288444786213277214628281832785420546274087146761566864614047504688123772643616870148637036486545882717162028017172706874088300344834424111884355042605060726257071061472334164583725618637172662277276238285574537252303708512187713753768210883717883214177506821154744051238430026270855363428730658126314153612053400077268874042185164222701426867051627554247573272557376740151571806220637182717476783435840540164172408587171868366825071315532702431761021552623061343345432712675051436011076617066231844451104348332548221106105114023473728208461760881801028437428634770630222621088305700346277351457830386857805275647013556147441362065165825384420633364237016227253566137375754313815436352300840071213800623627143462831576581300375511873047806550427070820275112032855056137212406102042344837643783510606621032343518643584052038422148828271478733221816003564556283801864300304433172707473414552811044246731560263787181360375220856023782825227102624663780175705186245881553055783106085313045005862533446468632134156855843085604348382611533515253722765723825136013746254432618268575605574880777370574873416807208456637441333184132067035322454017072312638668737073738377347585458061613007130848158715255752218380205816085742220815543528204180550315407345040343465616657842185850163106537650131781684036344622188084870842413154385436162802282440416080100438843655544106712445324162727681876878667304463852468413048081441201022820146183282812314331114888177386525521660163781083757743180378743438208686328556162024886323326120153038720833558641743826880113166153240558815120076524147752615042565452038541813882006275635438131506100314186187302343688270237767287844414752004085217272576403406754126201126712336183622843312501717384047822064857500303244180435065521612467421283018275707044616755208768040404760152323626173084386326286466747754211888301380460737572061342836367388845034654501045572058038063025335007602521812172166057474442286006578638145768783310135200717742254225860404885176720441047442166271805032286547386064076324568835101011406416753172855727057633455343825574000185777457428046681783622861257212832770071867083635215251007450841602618461842346412633483540142652201486041275081010667260201557331072426444618765328354076766417616130400424781247440566121265103547027280348113585104382410141813131455488838053702550808735183553830446408482367420076160076262663527670655562131264387255352825271342760566005822722332021348641167120856016554505570062536643673516223718301411084856100680157256766330732307710560350275148387768844636817022858087224581570845678335518432524511500037200041260067078007810158777163560526565081510773305010008850376420041473043255445606782654331804225784332044865574631035716102618467576882870067886585833110838276608241427536661612063618063214214585338564232814071202471515401656574782880713574621360444087084720607867137388445835311536257004364542878404634164452864246674118454286683235265786134857158678250347676325587704123207422854256630805386558578714726184126602861672885736446138500463533680748730338560546460428771824557181826464770402317772272740307477181478455585636075313283171573648400013054167571673116613571151510822374601535776316668534781321216853367674808200331442082688114414130302552638734526434061284204530625144825831481633217731670815133456452644081738063826088665353158124242484515531313451650213561416418085410405570606611140402142484384218384741442546410531674164472571000300215641678074334108435802784785688827488005837505826553888287125700643040881844334254155035271475167358430157130007013157486260051048760867051743488768342422141241284763218463632174454765861135173133286717111015542473116471513784372812532572507657618560461160572743554454317855102056287537832510205823506658075100270021761425488164177384714875436784437406006607216702405546421610285706140720336410004242104218828732364102102771261820130415166285786051016867117585071256587118755723107328726422080034138056203686821344515778507367155074361276125362022202351803832562288404317808420748687425723066470647261867532441741436340372734386377387536812712777758741523517725363013063628084148710814544350354128327450370108328345834184825032321204672125621760366274452185311667651381252480486872231627631122044224520137166555015885512810668513134734823527032322425078674033704700366250108836332352873123853430724168550066010372527701608883083567656658420863452247174555607068360358816616025006640012632030424828703053711305501480063563571055808404007667803548310285444582741013521587484871581873111322130771340805727521017815071546438331423181123825712415353283253055676286642757154578338046560888260426388261727558075655358131244258127644363553544161740513858558235265541018757524161706182667583126416834576488658808811147208535624307173833635764341270140176748648145554832612236561605878888234374007627452055011533720070776526077806626462013173033627356313122046445348831353878135766532587562735788641612802888058545633468326114560814135332856327735001740007712770551648528771444277478636812835258726114418280064621578160647816130504484417885455441310710237534854576868640827180867271531761050414728543450007823128426565157434460537338831685013827707746862257354742005884633255324034020140726006706533076110322584488787770046814060435340713051331121572716523741531875356702152315734851311371301664505011838574148782254327851402476184582057271422856838167763147707602848731788351754217448062810632163271832784804754855132333775805410764225072675773831382577208243836676513228533258804277348354423465462726763635586253784211383036438771457456004447381183528835587380018474478558760757488651234458158618285508566384516862071204682088461113757421315271543505317758616335700181150641341681041423844374066773814203773172040015357835077566066406714670073856536132620828836858568272876380471265510617104842623063547546011648218642120528241217201264418272541586085523518764050874346007711882466821876542475180688703464148317887712124820504824573450228111734537748838844660550575520873685472318251758020402465762411066627657844870521057325110206306425246704057182500708712735815425337147147484680845558170616553077740875373516455617458405322418668172025816470204565745732515143276215624473303535601018155746530745157426316131326448006255227746661304883216246242332321221046303207758322108418257570681028241142342484688526201382067331356726675158657337735228036833005140843574828268178828841221231212157311407301862716571557453483027852574588426386317222844845137486524171756112077772450745120438814043882721542500432780173282276283126542113737607746264233325574221587120848174301601886327120664423872308236666445766735274788115256514100204171708047626683537844852541635414486050687783225388745775154057484178630248743026361164786481223116305267273743145576636823725802764406413723436251762165820668803565807826085752366206338232114347130128821066058530265768254726576332032418730118514270183775054023384463034340706331703624150233863615660463048083263785543436400334336168067015171788458623687870730764865344561677627684365730626683072272624257375580502826520477760052580258620807556807623563026603046618634010113234004426635302058856310363212461781161353030781883726554753234473756114056038218043367517243478501237088565228021222257735670338820817870024347425161026158717204583758431002003234356520643035233555762368342114753878281652518156668068054210780825420587461040570476617171708256807440526301021557600786610784666273551445505075683164370060256603831838721252335608240674634433648778570417671457543258352862737344647424385202373703571366236526365774314152542608248523347802566388780166204546612148456535165672332228815853101305036068777746265720610677256370668701517100710332186638861005007310711864876551616102248756707824700427538726774173682441086323064411008186307371752102618060768502607627380178201343326340827013307717005315507127517241727734544314546316826358657803607532512068532335313084167267218766848485772658036626232251228241121145608623508757237303875624836550803486838238480781007152183824603204262111442105822411702738335005015331731517370266458832844686163274513052513143445663445645138422176610067282056232833531362883771248717505343234563001453584106746531048741017055621746366646150773232173061831068888866382201723777873735556684635566885100134773078406037346250430466763014315062572500326680833425582511220020804233713401314545117718084008434041613841270302837200388405753847723837030208332527585875058057764346701453767366355381480582356312063123418762453601741154336354218503285423233032455031888053657637446023116263037806702258215876864326411283205733020423242744783406845233527808618464288404304185036141087678562182326711378025403222216463781711163023683488586425024156028225301534471751801778118254806056605120208110044537253488272220720337416100518705316686511407527862467345875327140732360253782517501523302103632288166835628577115228462686218513817472506280223288028076843513285315285100421633053867834428803443
```

**Output (need to be):**

```
2
```

**Output with my code:**

```
4
```

So i don't know why is this happening because with another **input** my code is corrert:

```
763856354130136657360385516561520873045138714562332581204134142350730376283263680474653368757850487744860687174203110471643858602071801482028332653007166021826745174216138047817365348874514035821835612354050260544684725083051173324643825032336778782315104006603812742522771834088312702426100255155571471164588120604506466482133084060125572828026652740725300255036357264411565411313220610312477661525200624181273678765405170622003760807436012015546647124152462304506772560608127170466866433286314308076111732534314571162487345541117720317272124884630067232072656004285331281425165138177815136175542100311650333707342555832365361622315780463876462585205746384761118882137055072862101805442176434432204100601325362405055835148758015427383385114322832417385874425771288466408276226427662431076007266604531123285610451050580774714271542833845080001436232853660764311085680124630520500408800114274306755821766735740216024032300324714874556435420067888861610242771343152511705731160605244416176738413700221258437380040822775863133651778751211738450223765661576528804555312631150051080343763578868542634554368526333822067137015775230648240813186267232483470047125473601627341053116110277018577025244711848206154630086408583405243377832158881070838386616650275622740201355837112613225167544150076760876686687437824157810643238623035376176626013464366383165881501581054570782377367474818662273085618136500244702754070028836711466505422223042153582382870316175374820780744670187572281053042552333522136522460063685655230321850230236046606221767555035156666348610682685672858283014183766011436704361075434234124456752147833834811110648602534311607828673630167014010214853762411277664048424557438161681445011607235630404341508440814217855744175016074358350272755324876545487473277751734753378553246205084827232261611287686211273427857448171276116864645115258820041275040560465474772146438542184643252602451574158430138262022043256340221757528211417348241661373288441322588327746848234723120818482755778114478603430636437744812250072505662045741313625678162643547645055648750455875223558335531550864588817786283877062284676202818444760857748163561177317405675378462630271604223606503485528758641055610743733564552538477017350144102605615816482412455734188208707163860580652457783450451418444043300857505415584658811074731723222842772371678322840047352361531273433643063677401886518465376222687803576655160317208086728737014667870114387423180387477207077874548373254026433514131254778424332621000552175305788627840866162010103357607727137054058084747135075145827237602602550751458102011542757504244304754386465723634400852226538152618503058603500621173824642882510034110733072422021256507138673714786085262476240218077735880856236785561377704538477286631250223848718761345461341633752202643550117320307780533501404108507037045256817814285738880318564422836322713265887146816632472488385878560804805628138068502684877772080801570500632060020634751026342325005036165116407345860265756521710533601450110421412735046166370148372320354858855384455538852001200854374445327874810443614257318533171054717376752855102715544023273551280125152074823871037368145871374001111231535302078210687378318682248006648721508838864071270124521850040430463883400522814238655721532464053368042308325231264502030277332415144362510551004765254434777074016023140110854150705044415033281723875462545683042636672311863432500166770047028273032140573872737261673537040561630784337778887057476143740442084353580080833202125656344267723845416088835220820667515646872572420878775312107575745736146272106555521815846824608112642577763720502034022730453257700767811115641403014552686583713376027778256317227651825404567287218002523086080745584272785172566847107883166732360335523527877250520503320806348858606613416403242562868868134170620387153750184075382685277380050665544032023508256611047104277202414061004875626872732160248480317523135274231071317823157864623011663460074158680033502364232087046513751083468023635257267054650833816582473255018672115324373688885615605068683541222688784017610105573230674746308533031273056552814124513000128262665062473401424630217637373733542128236222257804358431140848385543085001375202038570856262101241050210166073055253710517487046547410034875606202033638552348687068545265511117105207778805460284233321584680215174150426461481553271732471124010254623404201610852756187412103672523365701581555125811711564383844225110016755403080612043706465700344618037232334153540453325620885466003424385252541244430370845172644232847213164075831524245134122266455733675014648015841781564665867644668464128116876118014752712750125224044762560738758328310758642000310784781871412172284242675178067541777245445383387540503251872434764770305821148084661630038185356686682318115573823042866403346053745751133568124186612871580883151360312847007008803227582374672743037340242823674407413056325542517185021134205620252366775208200064823886422241162006735853868638877477786133821115473824232201760731270667522850856055518462245543117045084503248851351452108403858241240224621533285056474050526630380275753318366727157450481516030125005682800758572356547247382376630120236285023834345010716080585807232401184404273432733020064278337065677335870205730243214740830572468815488584507137422201588308008353171531426283308866806800214083546628483757232554512231325824672637846146753563022676728575472630815131747862511186425175678413017284183600032377523161370615857228426216441670651321508540778103027285046137500830413281336378688114820684128521731657751518010707050357675552862833131164713006157316766532585147545848512145664466825384327114201113147776002142366261715863451642411525744443672043861217872570838088126424703842660226752806113251117174560238451758668525600210428466572842767316114440020052243554778737788862064663107527570807664170301178356786025037282065344006300066664078855573856763811061422417707587557008025483423025004343822287011234803822766765374540728128415248400366271010055714723674140588216153384530018863660481200376560286163083444238846821664406201226132183756850873446843773447472733335215077665786577138366650711538440337532564067211038513804671244304541677234642558862752687483668230813451713230581036554305487517305642341547002727358040231502322872466036573233112623747184701305147102242340461074000525773724681314444385142271831172242282106128821641837683156744828364377363647112668043105072583550110302186243342201435675863146700322312783245383428441532506357751768437250453722567858543037757436640236656643345041366240004761664022458120406517077383828555515000153123758160717474352831261322318407465420124722251650224571051741273403633434427121682671155580627438304044733286166144080510843443210434654852153834353525786424212843238703728783817615413783022718022432362430765676821417632134887667834006275050758051678025305467321844132606841363578310672834682561385251736043687764855173355035767050387255202262057625133562636500800240121100407874682380561057368140666210277655336057248825863816853341401220264668285354666623301326737711808416624103380865072285061540800005633578867821085625382440312055585737571655725738178626514523852136030086076157072710302437601326501508701758620334660245432543270717806880758034411561562683763163887446336155587384861156287657005734074003537654074653284110260676181325412877187528168734666271520607247252180017104088343324182851557471032677342316045738655470618385630116522627780047065281017556067817211275651457420636020808612820273002520306316580586080563558128188742642468043318336130005230352577058242045530768481747604750510611012867040057006446870051788848775665311374278206468757280320708011373885747120848724523673171436440851128532757420240160733240434548705141017533608143251516618205732658701660884504343748236136368085246867605563336508551825123428720853883252733510660325050747501432650003076323428318875525103123137434356727110647711414371827255332160338436255534510431314773718473508346410427014702423645426001156155752248331473813336752367720557038231407815643550056872830401101652154107574123642078818605184710045316822081026630451351732066087022272065254751131317405661547310056786746846138805221860542468231813626752864035880475085446870443858784613175522743543121844224315841131717275131238856855500178161846027605815001653207466463150131437845504411837324633271223806276775836788887173353821742663477644368547522322631308631772514256562461510534174204460016158764173520258202674655813114556774777078355684451231762538050158547751247183067326331384752282005087077028611333236448425020627810852875002736052467018877076654652044773518857242536841427776627164344008385638343411304537522710773676723586276747583433658501462382030027221083345253628151165017160233037611580364630320652162435871653288580314271676653333360626777270565650571515184520714711820167224423218144321611627733108670381586053634252733678450426382040428821735856374531350142554765486757543665158321821383007261711885375675137003616444706840667586544021222623471835765008507254778310230275088584303360822677281326766807302344883372153448072048810210605727424641014752681340304122862118000623188248154823000136522227277782380350202734473771163603184383400581232036372116046503128435120865347764426202814154301366768758374564643418344105136166728157437336147172848745260821852188351620243884055401284041761330855227177266661230258780126438676805778667471105134367300151724600360346203061353503721555243526536271404344130277330186810808260467582358267160641157658556842707151145157068340205342314861111447415621860400101265108166341806166531514636465602458287886752823638272116184053322180418851240228555056026770363502036664525266223086123266114873017123877345603775745244602252250408756513361778067548257582606543455888730834616705438377553157168523144160737216766065215775024027877561707416087530003045453326043720834644705333816324738254088141308802335013715806400077073757385261571831350365578855282768642663651711427602826446068482775202531175770641614332140381017487230605
```

**Output**:

```
1
```

Comment: if i do 6 zeroes result2 will be the same, if it will be with 7 zeroes i will get segmentation fault

Comment: read a single char each time: `int sod = 0; for (;;) { int ch = getchar(); if (ch == EOF) break; if (!isdigit((unsigned char)ch)) break; sod += ch - '0'; if (sod > 9) sod -= 9; } printf("sod is %d\n", sod);` ... [ideone](https://ideone.com/nPB1di) gets `6` as the answer

Comment: with second input output shoud be 1, not 6

Comment: Does shell has limit of line-length of `4096` chars?

Comment: Start by putting some logic in functions. This will help.

Comment: Why, exactly have you asked the same question again?  (Original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71677929/how-can-i-sum-realy-big-number).  This is an abuse of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement doesn't make sense to me, and your code needs nested loops.  The outer loop should repeat until the number has been reduced to be in the 0 to 9 range, and the inner loop should iterate over each digit of the number, calculating the sum of the digits.

Here is my cleaned up and working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>

uint64_t sum_of_digits(uint64_t x) {
  uint64_t sum = 0;
  while (x > 0) {
    sum += x % 10;
    x /= 10;
  }
  return sum;
}

int main() {
  uint64_t sum = 0;
  while (1) {
    int c = getchar();
    if (!isdigit(c)) { break; }
    sum += c - '0';
  }

  while (sum > 9) { sum = sum_of_digits(sum); }
  printf("Result: %d\n", (int)sum);
}
```

Note:  I tried to test this with your 9999-character input vectors but I am getting different results than what you claim is correct.  I am getting 9 for the first one and 6 for the second one.

**Update: A simpler way using math.**

Let's think about what actually happens when you calculate this "digital root".

- When you change 10 into 1, you are subtracting 9.
- When you change 100 into 1, you are subtracting 99, which is a multiple of 9.
- When you change 200 into 2, you are subtracting 2*99, which is still a multiple of 9.
- When you change 3578 into 3+5+7+8, you are changing 3000 into 3 and 500 into 5 and 70 into 7, which means you are just subtracting 9 many times.

Everything that this program is supposed to do is just subtract 9 from the number as much as it can, until the number is in the 1 to 9 range.  (This is not quite the same as `x % 9`, but pretty close.)

So we can simplify the program and make it *much* more efficient by taking advantage of this mathematical fact:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
  unsigned int result = 0;
  while (1) {
    int c = getchar();
    if (!isdigit(c)) { break; }
    result += c - '0';
    if (result > 9) { result -= 9; }
  }

  printf("Result: %u\n", result);
}
```

With this new program, I still get 9 and 6 as the answers for your large inputs.

Comment: so there is a problem, it cant be 9 and 6
it should be 2 and 1

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: because my university checks the code with tests, and it says what values are expected

Comment: I changed the code to read one character at a time, which should save memory and allow it to handle truly massive numbers.  I still get the results 9 and 6.

Comment: Оля Швенда, the correct result is 9 for the posted `"751...443"`.  I suspect you have the wrong data posted.

Comment: I posted a different, smarter way to calculate the answer, and I still get 9 and 6 as my results.  You can also double check these results using a programming language like Ruby that supports arbitrarily long integers.  Just take your huge number, add `% 9` on the end, and print it out.  (And note that if this method gives you 0 then the "digital root" is 9.)

Comment: David, nifty `if (result > 9) { result -= 9; }`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- you only allow for up to 99999 digits
- you do not check for input failure: undefined behavior if redirected forom an empty file.
- type `unsigned long long` is not required for `result`, `long` would suffice as 99999 * 9 is below 2<sup>31</sup>-1.
- for full portability, `idx` should have type `size_t`.
- `isdigit(buffer[idx])` has undefined behavior on platforms with signed `char` if the user typed non ASCII characters.
- the first test case posted has 9999 digits and a digit root of `9`, not `4` as you post, nor `2` as you expect. The second has a digit root of `6`, not `1`. There must be some mistake in the data.

Here is a much simpler solution:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, result = 0;
    while (isdigit(c = getchar()) {
        if ((result += c - '0') > 9)
            result -= 9;
    }
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```