# Trying to compare a hard defined string with a user defined string

Tags: c, scanf, c-strings, strcmp

Problem Statement

> Today is Newton School's first class of this year. Nutan, a student at
> Newton School, has received his first assignment. He will be given a
> string as input. His task is to print "Gravity'' if the input is
> "Apple''; otherwise, he will have to print "Space''.
>
> Can you help Nutan in solving his first assignment? Note that the
> quotation marks are just for clarity. They are not part of the input
> string, and should not be a part of your output string. Input The
> input consists of a single line that contains a string S (1 ≤ length
> of S ≤ 10). The string only consists of lowercase and uppercase
> letters. Output Print "Gravity'' or "Space'' according to the input.

**What I am trying to do:**
Basically, I am taking a user-defined string and trying to compare it with the hard input string i.e "Apple". If both the string matches then it will print "Gravity" or else it will print "Space"

```
#include <stdio.h> // header file for Standard Input Output
#include <stdlib.h> // header file for Standard Library
#include <string.h> // for strcmp() function

int main() {

    char str1[10]="Apple";
    char str2[20];
    int value;
    printf("Enter the input ");
    scanf("%s", &str2[20]);
    value = strcmp(str1, str2);
    if(value==0)
        printf("Gravity");
    else
        printf("Space");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well... Doesn't the code you provided works ? What happens ? What's your problem ? Edit : Oh right, I saw the error. You should explain what's actually your issue next time like, if you have compilation issues, or segfault or things like that.

Answer (score 3):

```c
scanf("%s", &str2[20]);
```

may invoke *undefined behavior* by out-of-range access. You should:

- Pass the pointer to *the first element* of the array, not one to the next element of the last element. (most) arrays in expressions are automatically converted to pointes to their first elements.
- Specify the maximum length to read to avoid buffer overrun.
- Check if reading succeeded.

The line should be:

```c
if (scanf("%19s", str2) != 1) {
    puts("read error");
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are entering a string starting from the memory address after the last element of the array str2

```
scanf("%s", &str2[20]);
```

and then trying to compare the character array str1 with the non-initialized array str2

```
value = strcmp(str1, str2);
```

Change the call of scanf like

```
scanf("%19s", str2);
```

And the program will be safer if at least the array str2 will be initially initialized

```
char str2[20] = "";
```

Also as the array str1 is not changed then instead of the array you could declare a pointer to the string literal like

```
const char *str1 = "Apple";
```

And instead of the calls of printf

```
    printf("Gravity");
    //..
    printf("Space");
```

it is better to use calls of puts

```
    puts("Gravity");
    //..
    puts("Space");
```

Pay attention to that neither declaration from the header `<stdlib.h>` is used in your program. So you may remove this include directive

```
#include <stdlib.h> // header file for Standard Library
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Some improvements:

- Don't use `"%s"`, use `"%<WIDTH>s"`, to avoid [buffer-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71232480/17939455)
- Instead of using bare `return 0;`, use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, which is defined in the header file `stdlib.h`.
- always check whether `scanf()` input was successful or not
- Use `const char *` instead of `char str1[10]`
- There's no need for `int value;`
- SYNTAX ERROR: `&str2[20]`
- There's no need for passing the address of `str2` [`READ MORE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior)
- Initialize `str2` with zeroes
- Add `1` more space in your `str2` for NULL (`'\0'`) terminating character

##### Final Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *str1 = "Apple";
    char str2[21] = {};
    printf("Enter the input ");
    if(scanf("%20s", str2) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "bad input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(strcmp(str1, str2) == 0)
        printf("Gravity");
    else
        printf("Space");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%20s", &str2)` will invoke *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `scanf()`: `char(*)[21]` is passed where `char*` is expected.

Comment: @MikeCAT I was editing it