# Why is this code producing an infinite loop?

Tags: c, debugging

```
#include <Stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char str[51];
    int k = 1;
    printf("Enter string\n");
    scanf("%s", &str);
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){
        while(str[k] != '\0')){
            if(str[i] == str[k]){
                printf("%c", str[i]);
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is simple C code that checks for duplicate characters in string and prints the characters. I am not understanding why it is producing an infinite loop. The inner while loop should stop when `str[k]` reaches the null terminator but the program continues infinitely.

Comment: You don't use `&` when scanning a string.

Comment: That code won't even compile, so I seriously doubt it to be producing an infinite loop. Dunno why everyone just dropped their comment, but assuming you fix the blatant syntax error in the posted code, their comments were correct: `k++;` belongs *outside* the `if` block in which it currently resides.

Comment: move `k++` after the `if` block, at least

Comment: @WhozCraig If you're talking about `<Stdio.h>`, that will likely work with a case-insensitive filesystem like Windows.

Comment: @Barmar I'm talking about `while(str[k] != '\0')){`

Comment: Both are probably just copying errors.

Comment: Is the intent of this exercise to print each character that appears more than once in the string, once? E.g. given `mississippi` , should the output be `sip` ? Or something else?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, your are right

Comment: Sorry, but when you say I'm "right", does that mean yes, the output should be a *single* character for each one found more than once (such as my example), or yes, it is something else. Details matter.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &str);`, without a _width_ is poor code.  Better as `scanf("%50s", str);`

Comment: @WhozCraig For **mississippi**, the output will be **ips**. If we look the output string was a set(mathematical one), then your **sip** and **ips** are equal. And yes, the program should print single character for each one found to occur more than once.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX That is what the output will be from *your* answer code. I've yet to hear back from the OP. As I said to them, details matter. If a duplicate is determined by foreshadow detection (e.g. scan forward on each new char) the first duplicated char is `i`. If duplicate detection is based on previous encounter the first duplicated char is `s`.  And both have the added distraction of "remembering" you already reported a character as a duplicate, and to not do it again; an easy task to accomplish with a lookup table; not so much with a double loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig In that sense OP should **provide further details**. I had given my answer as most of the people likes in that way to printing duplicate ones

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. As some users have pointed out, k++ within the if statement was a copying error. It is outside the if statement in the actual code. Not sure why it appears this way here. I have removed the "&" sign from scanf but the code is only printing the first character although that character is not unique. I have also changed the if statement to be true if the string character does not equal another string character. It is also no longer in the infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

##### Points to know

- You don't need to pass the address of the variable `str` to `scanf()`
- Don't use `"%s"`, use `"%<WIDTH>s"`, to avoid [buffer-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71232480/17939455)
- Always check whether `scanf()` conversion was successful or not, by checking its return value
- Always use `size_t` to iterator over any array
- `i < strlen(str)`, makes the loop's time complexity *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*, instead of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, which also isn't very good you should check whether `str[i] != 0`. But, many modern compilers of `C` will optimize it by the way.
- `#include <Stdio.h>` it is very wrong, `stdio.h` != `Stdio.h`
- Call to `printf()` can be optimized using `puts()` and `putc()` without any special formatting, here also modern compiler can optimize it
- `while(str[k] != '\0')){` has a bracket (`')'`)
- Initialize your variable `str` using `{}`, this will assign `0` to all the elements of `str`

---

##### Better Implementation

My implementation for this problem is that create a list of character (256 max) with 0 initialized, and then add 1 to ASCII value of the character (from `str`) in that list. After that print those character whose value was greater than 1.

- Time Complexity = *O(n)*, where `n` is the length of the string
- Space Complexity = O(NO_OF_CHARACTERS), where `NO_OF_CHARACTERS` is 256

  ---

##### Final Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

static void print_dup(const char *str)
{
    size_t *count = calloc(1 << CHAR_BIT, sizeof(size_t));
    for(size_t i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        count[(unsigned char)str[i]]++;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (1 << CHAR_BIT); i++)
    {
        if(count[i] > 1)
        {
            printf("`%c`, count = %zu\n", i, count[i]);
        }
    }
    free(count);
}

int main(void) {
    char str[51] = {};
    puts("Enter string:");
    if (scanf("%50s", str) != 1)
    {
        perror("bad input");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    print_dup(str);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Doesn't that confuses OP, I should typecast only the single character to `unsigned char`

Comment: "I should typecast only the single character to unsigned char' --> OK, except with rare non-2's complement encoding.  Best to access the string data via `const unsigned char *`.

Comment: It still lacks in various ways.  It does have many good points, so have an UV.

Answer (score 1):

Read your code in English: You only increment variable `k` if character at index `k` is equal to character at index `i`. For any string that has different first two characters you will encounter infinite loop: `char` at index `i==0` is not equal to `char` at index `k==1`, so `k` is not incremented and `while(str[k]!=0)` loops forever.