# Change values in a struct array

Tags: arrays, c, function, struct

Can someone explain me, please, why can't I insert values into a struct array.

Here's a piece of my code to help understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

I want to insert values inside an array which is formed by structs, whenever I try to insert values it gives me a segmentation error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAM_TABELA 10
#define PRIMO 7
#define MAX_NOME 50

typedef struct {
    char nome[MAX_NOME];
    int telemovel;
} pessoa;

void insert(pessoa *grupo[]) {
    char nome[MAX_NOME];
    printf("\nInsert name:\n");
    scanf("%s", nome);
    int lenght = strnlen(nome, MAX_NOME);
    printf("\nInsert phone:\n");
    scanf("%d", &tel);

    for (i = 0; i < TAM_TABELA; i++) {
        if (grupo[i] == NULL) {
            grupo[i]->telemovel = tel;
            strcpy(grupo[i]->nome, nome);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i == TAM_TABELA)
        printf("\nO valor não pode ser inserido!\n");
}

void main() {
    int opt;
    pessoa p;
    pessoa grupo[TAM_TABELA] = {NULL};

    insert(grupo);
}
```

Comment: Surely you get compiler warnings.  The `insert` functions expects an argument of type `pessoa **`, but you are passing a `pessoa *`.  Those are incompatible.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `if (grupo[i] == NULL) { grupo[i]->telemovel = tel;` ?  That is an error.  If `gropo[i]` is NULL, then attempting to reference the `telemovel` member of the struct with `grupo[i]->telemovel` is undefined behavior.  If the pointer does not address a valid struct, what are you trying to access?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm quite new to programming. I'm trying to insert values in the struct only if the struct is empty. I'm doing this because I'm tryng to implement a double hashing program.

Comment: There is a difference between the struct being "empty" (which I suppose means uninitialized) and a pointer being NULL.  If the pointer has a value of NULL, it does not point to a valid structure.  That is, it points to memory that you can neither read nor write.  This is very different than pointing to a structure which does not yet contain any valid data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to pass the address of `grupo` to `insert()` function.
2. `int main(void) { }` is a valid C `main()` function prototype
3. `size_t` is a valid data type for lengths, iterate through arrays
4. Always check whether `scanf()` conversion was successful or not
5. Do not use `"%s"`, use `"%<WIDTH>s"`, to avoid [buffer-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71232480/17939455)
6. `for( i = 0; i < TAM_TABELA; i++)` `i` was never defined
7. parameter of the function `insert()` should be `pessoa ***grupo`, in de-reference it later in your function like `*grupo`
8. Initialize your `char []` using `{}`, which are stored on stack memory

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    for (i = 0; i < TAM_TABELA; i++) {
>        if (grupo[i] == NULL) {
>            grupo[i]->telemovel = tel;
>            strcpy(grupo[i]->nome, nome);
>            break;
>        }
>    }
> ```

Notice how you've checked that `grupo[i]` *is* `NULL` and then you try to access a struct member on that value that is `NULL`.

You possibly want to check that `grupo[i] != NULL`, which should make member access safe.

Comment: Thank's for the response, I'm trying to update the value only if the struct is empty.

Comment: `grupo[i] == NULL` won't tell you that. Maybe something like `grupo[i] != NULL && strlen(grupo[i]->nome)` > 0`.